# How to prove ownership of sourcecode?

Tags: source-code-protection

I am looking for some online tools to help me preventing my digital products from cloning/copying under DMCA legally.
I am a PHP/WordPress developer, selling some premium plugins on my site, I found a man who is selling the items matching with a couple of items I coded originally but I am confused how I will verify my ownership if I proceed legally?

I apologize if I posted this question on wrong place, but any help regarding my question/request will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Comments in the code and keeping the code someplace, like the cloud, where you can produce the last update date, are about all you can do.  Other people can create the same WordPress plugin as you with their own code without violating your code copyright.

Answer (score 0):

Watermarking is what you need. This introduces small 'features' into the source code which you can later prove that it's yours. For example you can obviously choose distinctive variable names but these can be renamed. You can use distinctive layout i.e. whitespace characters. You can add redundant code that doesn't do anything but looks as though it does. If the copier retains this then it's pretty clear where it came from.

Additionally, you could obfuscate your code so the copier has a hard time understanding and therefore changing it. If your obfuscation is good enough then you could add code to nodelock it i.e. tie it to your domain and so then copying it to another domain will break it.